# CartThrob tax being calculated incorrectly

Tags: cartthrob, tax

I have a single tax rate of 10% set up for CartThrob (including shipping which is a flat rate up to $400 then free after that) but the value being output in the cart is incorrect, it's coming out at about 10.6%.

I thought as a stop-gap measure, I could reduce the tax rate a bit so that when CT incorrectly adds a bit more, it would come out at 10%, but no matter what rate I enter, it always comes out wrong and I can never get it to equal 10%.

I've tried using both tax by location – percentage and with standalone tax database, but the results are the same for both.

Comment: Do you think the shipping calculation is coming into play here? Or, if you test with free shipping, does the tax get applied correctly?

Comment: Still coming out the same without shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer to my problem was having the decimal places setting set to 2 when I needed 3 for my situation.